# How to deploy a datasource to jboss6 with maven

Tags: mysql, maven, jboss, datasource, ear

Is there a recommended way to deploy a mysql datasource and corresponding **mysql-connector-java.5.1.21.jar** using maven? Right now we have an ear deployment that installs the mysql-ds.xml, the connector j driver, an ejb.jar and a war file. It works but I also get this [stack trace](http://pastebin.ca/2170230) during startup of my JBoss 6 server. We don't have this issue if we place the mysql jar into the server\default\lib dir but we are hoping the datasource and driver jar can be part of our ear deploy.